# Angular-ui State - Multiple views not seeing my resolve data

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

For some reason, my resolvedData is not seeing by controllers when using multiple named views (angular-ui ui-router). Has anyone faced this issue?

```
$stateProvider
    .state('page',{
           abstract: true,
           templateUrl: ...,
           controller: abstractController
    })
    .state('page.index',
           url: '/page',
           resolve : {
               resolvedData: function(CONSTANTS){ return CONSTANTS.data;}
           },
           views: {
               home: {templateUrl: ..., 
                      controller: function(resolvedData){
                        ....
                      }
               },
               list: {templateUrl: ..., 
                      controller: function(resolvedData){
                        ....
                      }
               },
               edit: {templateUrl: ..., 
                      controller: function(resolvedData){
                        ....
                      }
               }
           }
     )
```

The error it gives me is: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: resolvedDataProvider <- resolvedData. It is somehow interesting because it happens only in one of the views but not in the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created [small working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/J1wRKBZspreLwAypal7i?p=preview), showing that your stuff should work

This would be the CONSTANTS:

```
.factory('CONSTANTS', function() {
    return { data: { name :  "some name", number : "some number"} };
})
```

And the same (just explicitly annotated DI) state def:

```
  // States
  $stateProvider
    .state('page', {
      abstract: true,
      template: '<div>' 
       + '<div ui-view="home"></div>' 
       + '<div ui-view="list"></div></div>',
      controller: 'abstractController'
    })
    .state('page.index', {
      url: '/page',
      resolve: {
        resolvedData: ['CONSTANTS',
          function(CONSTANTS) {
            return CONSTANTS.data;
          }
        ]
      },
      views: {
        home: {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
          controller: ['resolvedData','$scope',
            function(resolvedData, $scope) {
              console.log(resolvedData);
              $scope.resolvedData = resolvedData;
            }
          ],
        },
        list: {
          template: '<div>list view</div>'
        }
      }
    })
```

So, the draft of the resolve used above is working. It is the right way...The resolve function is provided with some service ... and returns its property `data`.

Check that all [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/J1wRKBZspreLwAypal7i?p=preview)

Comment: Ok... so it has to be then some duplication or missed type thing. Im leaving this open until I solve it. Thanks for the plnkr. Its enough to know that it should be working :)

Comment: Great to see that... yes, I would expect some typo... Good luck with `UI-Router` anyhow

Comment: Just for the readers, I ended up writing the resolve in the abstract state, defining a controller and filling the $scope with the data I need. Children state can see this information properly. Really similar to what it is defined in Nested States and Nested Views (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views). http://plnkr.co/edit/gmtcE2?p=preview

Comment: @Pureferret The example written by Radim Köhler demostrates that it should be working. I guess that I had some typo. Do you still need help with it? Did you experience the same issue?

Comment: @kitimenpolku I was trying to adapt it to something slightly different. I've got mine working though. Thanks for asking.